# Looking for a Tool, that allows me to "Union" many overlapping layers, while prioritizing some to overwrite the others in ArcGIS

Tags: arcmap, attribute-table, overlapping-features, union

I am currently working on a project where I analyze the contents of a 500m buffer around several sample points.

Foundation for those informations are multiple shape file layers, which, alltogether, cover the area without having blank spaces. Unfortunately, this also results in overlapping as seen here.

[image]

Due to different dates of creation of the data, I want to prioritize recent data and not older ones. So during a Union of my data, I would like to know if there is a way for hand-selected, "newer" data to overwrite older data, thus resulting in a more compromised data table which would then enable me to pie chart the contents, according to the percentage of area it has in my 500m buffer Clip.

I would also accept how to get to my goal differently than by messing with Union and Table content managing.

Comment: There is no tool which accepts manual override in an automatic process, but you could certainly automate your desired logic.

Comment: can you elaborate on that? Coding work implied? I haven't had too much experience with that so far, it would probably take me quite a while to read into that. Any recommendation?

Comment: Not just a little coding. Possibly weeks of work for an experienced developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Update tool from the "oldest" layer to the most recent and  you will get the result your looking for.

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/update.htm

Comment: Had a quick look on it. It seems as if it does work according to what I was looking for, though just for one input at a time.

Comment: You just need to build a model. The solution you proposed was my other.option but the update tool requires less steps to produce the same result.

Comment: Yes you are correct :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for my problem, by using intersections and erases in a specific order, thus resulting in a priority I could decide beforehand.

[image]

highest priority is at the top, while lowest is at the bottom.

[image]

Basically I intersected two overlapping features, used the intersect as input for an Erase command on the lower priority polygon and afterwards merged the result of Erase with my higher priority Polygon. As you can see, this can be done an endless amount of times, as need be. Every overlap is covered using this system. If polygons have the same priority, you would still use the same system, as it then doesn't matter, from which polygon I afterwards Erase the intersected part due to them being same priority.
A bonus to all this is, that my table afterwards includes all information the partial tables already owned, which in turn enables me to calculate my pie charts afterwards easier.

Not sure, if I expressed myself well here, but this worked just fine for what I was intending to do.